# Converting Weather Data for Better Modeling

Tags: weather

I am trying to use weather data to develop a better model for plant growth. Here is an example daily average solar insolation (W/m^2) vs cumulative daily insolation readings:
[image]

The cumulative insolation data is much easier to interpolate and I would like to do the equivalent for temperature. Since degrees Celsius/Fahrenheit are not additive in the same manner as Watts/m^2, I assume I will need to convert the temperature to Joules or some other unit of kinetic energy...
The challenge gets a little more complicated as I assume the heat capacity of air will vary with variables as atmospheric pressure, elevation, humidity and temperature... All of these quantities are known/measured. Is there an appropriate thermal conversion to units that are additive? Joules/m^3? Any suggestions would be appreciated. The data is in csv format and I am using a spreadsheet for the hourly recordings

Comment: You might consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_day

Comment: The degree days are helpful but they require a threshold temperature and they record minutes. Additive energy units might be more useful in comparing growth... ie: 10 hours of 70 degrees vs 10 hours of 80.

Comment: Well, where I grew up, the newspaper provided degree days as part of the weather report. It does not require 'minutes' but only the mean (average of high and low) temperatures on a day vs the reference temperature. Sure, you might need a different reference temperature than that used for heating, but the difference is easy to calculate.

Comment: I guess I was referring more to Growing Degree Days (https://mrcc.purdue.edu/gismaps/info/gddinfo.htm#:~:text=Growing%20Degree%20Days%20(GDD)%20are,or%20base%20temperature%20(TBASE).

Comment: both the Growing Degree Days and Modified Growing Degree Days also only use mean temperatures (with some variations on how to calculate them). Seems like a fairly tractable problem, particularly if some ag extension has a table of threshold temperatures for your plants of choice.

Comment: It is proving to be something we need to develop in house. The GDD's have a reference temperature, but they return accumulated minutes at that temperature (or below in the case of Chill Hour requirements).

Comment: Regardless, latitude plays a role in the equation. ie: 10 hours of 80 degrees in Anchorage vs at the Equator... Due to differing Insolation at different times of the growing season. The reason for want/need for accumulated units is: a more accurate Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) that is easily converted back into a Normal Probability Function (PDF). This will allow me to compare growth rate and separate the contribution of Insolation vs Temperature (Perhaps). Also, crop coefficients are not always established and certainly not for all latitudes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139334/discussion-between-chris-barry-and-jon-custer).

Comment: Frankly, that all sounds really really cool (so to speak). Is there an ag school or county ag person nearby to discuss with? Probably a bunch of research on this, but not in physics departments.

Comment: Not physics? PV=nRT... I was hoping there is a way to convert temperature into kinetic energy per unit volume... where P and T are known... and the contributing factor of humidity on the heat capacity per unit volume... not much of a question I would pose to a botanist